# Aqua Scanner complains about ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

Tags: docker, security, apache2

Building a docker container with base image ubuntu:focal; the container has postgressql database for storing data and apache2 for handling HTTP requests. Unfortunately, image cannot be deployed to prod because aqua scanner (security tool) complains about sensitive file

```
/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

How to make the container secure?

Tried setting a different user that container is run with

Answer (score 0):

The image is unsafe to use, because it contains a private key.
That means that everyone who has access to the image has the same private key than you and can therefore decrypt any captured traffic.
Never store private keys inside images. Create new ones with your entrypoint on the first start. If you install the package ssl-cert make sure to delete the automatically created "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" key in the same layer/RUN as where you install that package.